# How do I find the matching ID for the kth smallest element using Excel VBA?

Tags: vba, algorithm, excel, excel-formula

Lets' say I have two columns `col1` and `col2` (they are both range object, for instance, `set col1 = range("A1:A100")` `set col2 = range("C1:C100")`) where `col1` is an ID column whose values are 1,2,3, ..., 100 as row number increases. And it's easy to find kth smallest number in `col2` using `k_val = WorksheetFunction.Small(col2, k)`. Now I want to find the matching ID in `col1` that corresponds to the kth smallest value in `col2`. What should I do?

I know `vlookup` is able to solve this issue, but there's a flaw: if `col2` have two or more values that are equal to `k_val`, I may not get the correct ID. Also, I don't really want to sort the two columns based on `col2` for the reason that I don't want to change raw table (you may argue that I can first copy the raw table into another sheet, but anyway...), so is there any alternatives that I can use to solve this problem wisely?

Comment: Without knowing how you expect to handle the issue of determining the correct ID when there are two or more k_vals the same, it's hard to recommend anything.

Comment: Agree with @RonRosenfeld. Other than that, this is just another 'return multiple matches with VLOOKUP` question. The only problem is determining **which** matched row to return and you have decided that wasn't important enough to include in your question's narrative.

Comment: *"but there's a flaw: if col2 have two or more values..."* : (as in the above comments), the flaw until now is in the *specification* of how you want to deal with this case.

Comment: Thanks@RonRosenfeld@Jeeped @A.S.H, Now, what if I regard all the values as kth smallest element and want to find all the matching IDs?

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous ways to achieve that...

Like one given below...

```
Sub getIDForKthSmallestElement()
Dim col1 As Range, col2 As Range
Dim k As Integer
Dim k_val

Set col1 = Range("A1:A100")
Set col2 = Range("C1:C100")

k = 2 'second smallest value

On Error Resume Next
k_val = WorksheetFunction.Small(col2, k)

If k_val > 0 Then
    col2.AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=k_val
    col1.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Range("D1")   'will write all the ID's in column D
    col2.AutoFilter
End If
End Sub
```